# Aliasing doesn't have any effect

Tags: linux, git, shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline script.

Within it, this works:

```
sh("/my/path/to/git status")
```

However, if I try:

```
sh("alias git='/my/path/to/git' && git status")
```

OR

```
sh("alias git='/my/path/to/git'")
sh("git status")
```

These don't work: `script.sh: line 2: git: command not found`

I would like to make the second and third piece of code work as well. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not granted that consecutive `sh` calls keep the state (including environment variables).

Create a script in your project and call it in a single `sh` instruction, either that or use:

```
sh """
  alias git='/my/path/to/git'
  git status
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

These lines

```
sh("alias git='/my/path/to/git'")
sh("git status")
```

create *two* subshells. The first creates your alias, and then immediately exits. The second starts up with no knowledge of the previous shell or its alias.

The previous version

```
sh("alias git='/my/path/to/git' && git status")
```

doesn't work in a local interactive shell either, even when `&&` is replaced with `;` - clearly the alias simply doesn't take effect until the end of the current command list.

If you must use an alias, you should add it to whichever shell file (`.bashrc`, `.profile`, etc. etc.) is sourced when starting a shell. Note however that aliases may anyway not be expanded in non-interactive shells unless you `shopt -s expand_aliases`.

Otherwise, the usual solution would be to just add `/my/path/to` to your `$PATH`.